# Add Checked Attribute to Custom User Fields on Frontend User Form

Tags: custom-field, usermodel, drop-down

I have a multi-select for users to sign up for newsletters.
When they edit their profile they need to be able to see which newsletters they are already signed up for. I have the code to output the entire options list or just the ones that they have selected but I haven't figured a way to add the selected attribute to the ones the user has selected.

```
{% set newsletters = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('newsletters') %}
<select multiple>
    {% for opt in newsletters.settings.options %}
        <option value="{{ opt.value }}" >{{ opt.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The "for opt in newsletters.settings.options" can be changed to "for opt in newsletters.settings" to show just the ones the user has already selected.

Comment: Guessing this should work but form reloads page and doesn't save
{% set newsletters = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('newsletters') %}
<select name="fields[newsletters]" id="newsletters" multiple>
{% for opt in newsletters.settings.options %}
{% set created = false %}
{% for opti in newsletters.settings %}
{% if opti.value == opt.value %}
<option value="{{ opt.value }}" selected="selected">{{ opt.label }}</option>
{% set created = true %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if created == false %}
<option value="{{ opt.value }}">{{ opt.label }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>

Comment: Do you want to know get to know how to save your changes into the database?

Comment: Yes, I need it to save the changes and also have a way to add selected or some attribute if the user had previously selected that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

```
{% for letter in currentUser.newsletters.options %}
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ letter.value }}" name="{{ letter.value }}" id="{{ letter.value }}"
        {% if letter.selected == true %}checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
    <label for ="{{ letter.value }}">{{ letter.label }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```